# form event target undefined

Tags: javascript, forms

I’ve been using the below patter for many occasion, however at this occasion the `event.target` is `undefined`. Could someone explain why is that ?

```
<script language="javascript">
        function ValidateForm(e){
        var event = e || window.event;
        var trigger = event.target || event.srcElement; 
        console.log(trigger);
        return false;
       }    
</script>    

<form name="my_form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this)">
    <input type="submit" value="ok"></input>
</form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8WPP/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `e` in your `ValidateForm` points to `<form>` and not to the event. If you do `console.log(e)` in your function you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: I've already tried that and it returns the form object, but I am interested why it does not return which element has triggered that event in case there is more than one submit button. I guest I would do `onclik` and then submit the from from the `onclick` handler.

Comment: Yes, parameter of the onSubmit is actually the form which is being submitted (there is no event). If you need onClick event, you should attach it to the submit button.

Comment: _"parameter of the onSubmit is actually the form which is being submitted (there is no event)"_ that helps, thanks.